# whenever I try to deploy in VS Code it returns this error sf:UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Tags: vs-code

```
sf:UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION:
```

An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support:

`1437374837-49598 (109636631)`

if I try the error a few more times, but sometimes it comes back for no reason

Comment: Does this error happen for every file or specific one? Do edit your question and share sfdx and node version. Also try upgrading your sfdx with update command `sfdx update` to most recent version and try saving again.

Comment: can be with any code, the sfdx is updated, I got to format my computer and reinstall everything but the error still happens

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling of all Salesforce Extensions solved the issue for me.

Coz I tried with sfdx force:source:deploy and was working, so issue was in Salesforce Extension Pack.